# When a syntax error gives the error 500?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

The lav52.dev page isn’t working
lav52.dev is currently unable to handle this request.
500
laraver 5.2
ubuntu 14.04
php 5.6
lamp-server

```
Route::get('/','TestController@index');

class TestController extends Controller
{
 function index()
    {
        echo "index" // I do not have a ;

    }
}
```

Comment: if `echo "index" // здес не написал ;` is your real code, you misplaced the semi-colon. `echo "index"; // здес не написал` and would be a typo. Error 500, check your logs.

Comment: you do not understand me I did not write '; '

Comment: *`I do not have a ;`* well you need one. Your code will fail because of it. So do `echo "index";`

Comment: if I write ';' everything will be OK
but I need that for syntax errors produces a syntax error instead of error 500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set up apache's `DocumentRoot` to a `public` directory which is inside root Laravel project directory. I'm pretty sure you've set up it to a root directory, bot `public`, that's why you're getting 500 error.

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/lav52.dev/public

Comment: Is `lav52.dev` a physical directory? Or is it some kind of binding?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be your database thing. 
I use MAMP on my local as server. Once i add new data to my table then my server breaks. Then i was thinking something error in my table structure. I recreate it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give your tmp folder 777 permission?

Give permission to Storage folder to 777 and run the command
'php artisan optimize' in your app's directory